# Login, user authentication, session and csrf tokens

Tags: php, database, session, authentication

I started learning PHP about a month and a half ago, and I started doing so by trying to create my own very simple CMS in order to learn how to construct basic CRUD scripts that would interact with a mysql database and so on.

I am currently building my login form for the private admin section of my CMS and by doing so I wanted to learn about basic security in PHP.

I wanted to do some basic research on user authentication but the explanations I came across often included information on best security practices which I did not fully understand.

So, I looked for more information on the small bits I did not understand which included other bits I was not acquainted with and I got dragged into absorbing a lot of information on security topics like security through obscurity, one way password hashing, security through proper php configuration setup, defending against sql injection, php injection, session hijacking and so on.

I am having trouble implementing all this since I can't really make sense of it all.

So the first question is about storing the user session in the database.

What I know at this moment is that if I am using a shared host, the server might not be configured properly and the folder where the server is storing the session might be accessed by other people.

Is this the only reason why I would like to store the session in the database?

Second, how does storing the session in the db solve the access problem?

To elaborate on my confusion, it is clear to me that once the session is stored in the database it safe from the people on the shared host, but how do I tell php -"Hey, I stored my user session in the database, exclude it from wherever you are instructed to store it by default"?

In other words, just because I stored the session in the database does not mean that the server excluded it from the place where it stores the sessions by default. Is this correct, and if it is how do I take control over that?

Third, how do I actually store the session in the database? I assume the following process:

```
session_start();

//Assume a user has successfully logged in
//For better security regenerate the session on login
$session = session_regenerate_id();

$data[]= $session;

$query = $db_connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `sessions`(`session`) VALUES (?)");
$query->execute($data);
```

Is this what it means to store the session in the database in its most basic form?

Moving on to the next question.

Lets assume that I have resolved the issue above. Now how do I authenticate if a user is logged in?

Normally I would do something like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    redirect_to('login.php');
}
```

But since the user session is stored in the database, is it available to me directly or do I need to pull it out of the db first in order to use it?

I am aware of the fact that once a session starts there is an encrypted/hashed (don't know exactly which one it is)session cookie in the browser called PHPSESSID.

But since I am storing the session in the database to me it means I am taking manual control of what PHP usually does automatically, which in my head the process chain is generate->store->encrypt/hash->set session cookie.

Is that assumption correct?

And lastly cross site forgery requests.

My understanding is that while a user is logged in, he is tricked somehow to click on a link, etc. that will copy his browser's cookies and now the attacker is in possession of the session cookie and can impersonate the user.

How does a csrf token stored in a hidden field on my forms help in this situation?

If the attacker has hijacked the session of the user checking the token against the session does not help since the attacker has a valid session.

What am I missing?

There are knowledge gaps in my head on how things work, I hope you can somewhat fill these for me.

Comment: You are asking a lot of questions in a single one, you should isolate them, cause right now it's too big to be answered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is this the only reason why I would like to store the session in the
   database?

**The database is password protected, the sessions directory isn't. This goes without saying that most servers should secure the /tmp/session path (iirc) and nobody can access it.. but again, you'd have to trust the host quite a bit.**

2. Second, how does storing the session in the db solve the access problem?

**See answer #1**

3. In other words, just because I stored the session in the database does not mean that the server excluded it from the place where it stores the sessions by default. Is this correct, and if it is how do I take control over that?

**Basically, sessions are identified with a unique IDentifier. The browser is sent a cookie with the ID, and the server reads the cookie ID and references it to a configured location on the server. To set the save path, you can use [`session_set_save_handler`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) - this will allow you to do whatever you want with the session (on save) - such as save it to a DB. See Example #2.**

4. Now how do I authenticate if a user is logged in?

**There are various ways to determine if a user is logged in. A basic way is to store unique data in a session and relate it to the users table. When the browser sends the session ID, the server can then retrieve the data based on the ID. You can then take this data and cross-reference it with your users table to authenticate the user. Remember, servers are (typically) stateless, meaning navigating between pages, the server doesn't keep track of users between pages. Hence the use of sessions. A very basic example, and I wouldn't use this, is such:

```
<?php
function isLoggedIn() {
  if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $uuid = $_SESSION['user']['uuid']; // universal unique id
    $username = $_SESSION['user']['username']; // username
    $last = $_SESSION['user']['last']; // last use of session
    if($last > time() - 600) { // active last 10 minutes?
      $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE uuid = :uuid");
      $stmt->bindValue(":uuid", $uuid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      if($username == $user['username']) { // user is logged in. uuid on session matches uuid in users table
        $_SESSION['user']['last'] = time();
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  session_destroy(); // clear everything!
  return false;
}
?>
```

5. But since the user session is stored in the database, is it available to me directly or do I need to pull it out of the db first in order to use it?

**Don't confuse user session with the user object itself. The session is used to tie the actual USER and the APP together. See above answers & example**

6. How does a csrf token stored in a hidden field on my forms help in this situation?

**When you have CSRF tokens in your forms, you also have the CSRF token on the server... Meaning when the page with the form is loaded, a CSRF token is generated and stored in a session for the specific user. Remember, users who have session cookies do NOT have data -- just identifiers. The form will also have a hidden field, such as `csrf_token`. On POST, the server will compare the post token with the session. It will ALSO reset/clear the token so that it cannot ever be posted/used again. These tokens should be unique.. usually something like `md5(time())` works well. If the token doesn't match, or is missing, it's possible there's an attack. The best action to take here is to display the form again, with a new CSRF token.**